# I have Created a Site Workflow and After the workflow is saved as a template then display Error Show Using Sharepoint 2013 designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have developed a Site Workflow using Sharepoint 2013 designer.

I have published it on a site

Now as I try to "Save as Template" to make it as a ".WSP" I get an error that

"**The server was not able to create the template because the site does not contain any site asset library. Please Create the site asset library and then try again**."

though I have created Site assets library in the existing site .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, I have observed that you are using a Team site that has a Site Assets library by default. So creating a manual Site Assets library will not solve the issue so  try to do the following:

- Try to remove the manually created library,
- Open your site again via SharePoint Designer, and before save the workflow as a template.
- Just click on Site Assets in left navigation below `site objects`,
- And from the above ribbon click on `preview in browser` to make sure it's created within your site.
- Then come back to save your workflow as a template that should be now saved in Site Assets.

[image]

Comment: Preview Button already Disabled!!!!!